# Bash: interactively enter and save large html block into a variable from the terminal

Tags: bash, prompt, read, input, stdin

This is simple

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "What is your name?"
read name
echo "Your name is: $name"
```

But what if I don't want to treat a name but a large HTML code block with nested tags and all their special characters? (a block that will be interactively pasted)

How can i save an entire html code block into a variable with a bash script over the terminal input?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of reading a line with `read` you can read directly from the input with `cat`. This will read from *stdin* (typically the terminal if you type it directly at the prompt) and write to *stdout* (also the terminal). Use Ctrl/D to end your input:

```
cat
```

In the more general case the `cat` command reads from one more files listed as arguments, or *stdin* if none are specified, and writes the contents of all inputs to *stdout*.

Putting this into your program,

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "What is your name?"
name=$(cat)
printf 'Your name is: "%s"\n' "$name"
```

In this instance the output is sent to the variable `$name`.

Comment: This seems to be a simple solution, however it also seems to truncate the pasted code after 4096 characters. I googled a bit and it seems it is a default in the kernel but I didn't quite understand how to increase the number of characters allowed. I wouldn't want to change anything outside the script in question.

Comment: Please try pasting the same block into an unscripted `wc -c`. After the paste has been accepted (i.e. if necessary you've hit <Enter> to get it accepted), please hit <Enter> to get a newline, and then Ctrl/D to signify end of input. Is the result from `wc -c` approximately 4100 or approximately 8190? (I'm not fussed about ±10 bytes or so; it's the overall size). I'm curious to know if there's a 4kbyte limit on the paste buffer.

Comment: It's 4096 precisely. Two returns yields 4097. If pasted into emptyfile, then `wc -c emptyfile` yields 7038, and another pasted block yielded 15000 something while the first interactive `wc -c` yielded 4096 again. So, yes, there seems to be a paste buffer in play.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like

```
read -r -d name <<-EOF
```

to insert your code. You can paste in as many lines as you want. Enter a bare `EOF` on a single line to end the input.

Comment: when I do that the script fails:
warning: here-document at line 7 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `EOF')

Comment: The answer given by @roaima is a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

With `zsh` instead of `bash`, you can use its `vared` variable editor which uses zsh's line editor (zle) and allows embedding newlines in the input:

```
#! /bin/zsh -
text=
vared -p 'text: ' text
printf 'Got: <%s>\n' "$text"
```

To enter a literal newline in the text, enter <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, or <kbd>Esc</kbd> followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd> if <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> is already bound to something else in your environment, or
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> followed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>, (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> sends the `^J` aka newline or `\n` character while <kbd>Enter</kbd> sends the `^M` aka carriage return or `\r` one) like you would at the zsh shell prompt.

<kbd>Enter</kbd> alone submits the text.

You can  add a `bindkey '^M' self-insert-unmeta` before the call to `vared` for <kbd>Enter</kbd> to enter a literal newline and let the user submit the text with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> (or bind any other key or key combination to `accept-line`).

As zle supports [the bracketed paste feature supported by several terminal emulators and enables it by default](//security.stackexchange.com/a/52655), you should be able to paste multi-line text there. If bracketed paste cannot be enabled, rebinding `^M` as above should work as terminal emulators usually transform `\n`'s to `\r`'s when pasting.

Note that there are many control characters that terminal emulators won't let you paste as a safety reason, and even if you configure them to allow them, some, like `^C`, `^Z` will be intercepted by the tty device to send SIGINT, SIGTSTP signals. Shouldn't be a problem for HTML text though.

---

`bash` has `read -e` to use its line editor to read text from the user. `bash`'s line editor (`readline`) can also let you enter literal newlines with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> followed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>.

So there, you could do the same with:

```
IFS= read -e -rd $'\r' -p 'text: ' text
printf 'Got: <%s>\n' "$text"
```

Note that it won't let you embed `^M` characters in the text. Though you could use `-d ''` instead of `-d $'\r'` to read until a NUL and submit the text with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> instead of <kbd>Enter</kbd> as anyway bash variables can't contain NUL characters.

`readline` now does also support bracketed paste and newer versions also enable it by default. With older versions, you can add:

```
set enable-bracketed-paste`
```

to `~/.inputrc` or add:

```
bind 'set enable-bracketed-paste' 2> /dev/null
```

To the script prior to the `read` call.

---

Or you could use moreutils' `vipe` to run the user's preferred editor to enter the text:

```
text=$(vipe</dev/null)
```

If you don't have `vipe`, in `zsh`, you could do the same with:

```
(){
  ${VISUAL:-${EDITOR:-vi}} $1
  text=$(<$1)
} =()
```

Beware those remove trailing newline characters.

---

A pre-seeding can be done with all methods with:

```
text=seed; vared -p 'text: ' text
```

```
IFS= read -e -rd $'\r' -i seed -p 'text: ' text
```

```
text=$(echo seed | vipe)
```

```
(){
  ${VISUAL:-${EDITOR:-vi}} $1
  text=$(<$1)
} =(echo seed)
```

---

Also note that except for the `read -e` one, all those solutions only work interactively. You won't be able to do `echo some text | those-scripts` for instance. You could however add a check to see if stdin comes from a terminal and use `text=$(cat)` when it's not:

```
if [ -t 0 ]; then
  # stdin is a terminal, use any of the solutions above
else
  text=$(cat)
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you did not mention temporary files being forbidden, I have a wonky solution using a text editor:

```
# Variables
INPUT_TEXT=
TEMP_FILE=temp.html

# Set default editor for the system as nano unless defined
# Hard-code if you can, more consistent usage and users cannot invoke any program they desire through environment variable
EDITOR="${EDITOR:=nano}"

# WARNING: This line here might be a security issue, as it exposes use of a text editor freely, even if you hard-code the editor.
# Get input in a subshell (that's the key part here)
# The &3,&1,&2 redirections are beyond my grasp, but it is said it swaps stdout and stderr. The end goal here is to get TUI interaction with the subshelled command (likely nano in this script).
$( ${EDITOR} $TEMP_FILE 3>&1 1>&2 2>&1 );

# If above subshell ran successfully and user exitted saving the file
if [ $? = 0 ] && [ -f $TEMP_FILE ];
then
  INPUT_TEXT=$(cat $TEMP_FILE);

  # Remove temporary file, only when actually created
  rm $TEMP_FILE;
fi;

echo "$INPUT_TEXT"
```

In one-liner form:

```
EDITOR=${EDITOR:=nano}; INPUT_TEXT=; TEMP_FILE=temp.txt; $($EDITOR $TEMP_FILE 3>&1 1>&2 2>&1); if [ $? = 0 ] && [ -f $TEMP_FILE ]; then INPUT_TEXT=$(cat $TEMP_FILE); rm $TEMP_FILE; fi; echo "$INPUT_TEXT"
```

Edit: If you want to use specifically HTML, to be able to use syntax highlighting set file extension accordingly.